# OLS coefficient estimation with Poisson errors

Tags: regression, least-squares, normality-assumption, poisson-regression

Assume that in this regression
$$
Y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x+\epsilon,
$$
where $\epsilon$ follows a Poisson distribution. Using OLS, estimate $\beta_0,\beta_1$ and $\text{cov}(\beta_1,\beta_0)$.

I am wondering if the distribution of errors changes the $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ OLS estimators? If we used the normal procedure of deriving $\beta_1,\beta_0$, the result would be the same, but I think I am wrong.

Comment: Of course: At the very least, the fact that $E[\epsilon] \ne 0$ will change the expectation of $\hat\beta_0.$ For more insight, research weighted least squares, generalized least squares, and the effects of heteroscedastic responses on ordinary least squares estimates.